# How to retrieve data using SPARQL query?

Tags: protege

Can somebody help me for writing SPARQL query, because I can't understand its syntax?

[This is my ontology](HTTP://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Nu5Ej4okDIYU5CNG12N1BoMDA).

This is my ontology for wellness prediction for patients.
Is this possible to display the patient id and status of the patient whether they are in risk or not in risk of heart attack using SPARQL query?

Comment: HTTP://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Nu5Ej4okDIYU5CNG12N1BoMDA this is my ontology

Comment: Can you summarize or provide a small example here?  That might attract more responses.

Comment: my inputs are patient's name,id,gender,age,blood sugar level,blood pressure,heart rate,symptoms,having the habit of smoking,drinking alcohol or not,hereditary diseases.i need output as patient name and status(prone to heart attack) in the form of Risk/not in risk.is this possible to get?